# Hibernate spatial index annotation

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations, spatial-index, oracle-spatial

I am using **jts geometry** object to store my geometry objects as an Oracle SDO_Geometry. However when I want to use **SDO_GEOM.RELATE** methods they are not working properly,I realized that I need to create a **spatial index** but dont know how to do with **hibernate**. Do you know any annotation for this problem.

```
@Type(type="org.hibernate.spatial.GeometryType")
 private Geometry area;
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, just create the index on the table where you store those geometries. Use SQL for that.

You need also (before you create the index) to add the proper metadata so that the index creation has the proper information it needs (coordinate system, bounds, tolerance). For example, assuming your geometries are in WGS84 coordinates:

```
insert into user_sdo_geom_metadata (table_name, column_name, diminfo, srid)
values (
  'US_CITIES', 
  'GEOMETRY',
  sdo_dim_array (
    sdo_dim_element('long', -180.0, 180.0, 0.5),
    sdo_dim_element('lat', -90.0, 90.0, 0.5)
  ),
  4326
);
commit;
```

Then create the index:

```
create index us_cities_sx on us_cities (geometry)
  indextype is mdsys.spatial_index;
```

Comment: Well, I created index as you told still have some problems when I try to validate my geometry with SDO_GEOM.VALIDATE_GEOMETRY I got 13349 error.

Comment: First of all use SDO_GEOM.VALIDATE_GEOMETRY_WITH_CONTEXT(). Then error 13349 means that your shape (a polygon) is "twisted",i.e "self-crossing". You will not be able to use for any actual processing (searches, measurements, buffering, unioning, etc.). I have no idea how you construct your objects, or where you get them from, but that one is wrong and you must correct it.